# Show that there are at least two points on a manifold to which a vector is normal

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds

Let $M \subset \mathbb R^3$ be a $2$-dimensional manifold which is also a compact set. And let $v \in \mathbb R^3$ be a vector which satisfies $ ||v|| = 1$.

The task is to prove that there are at least two points $x,y \in M$ such that $v$ is a normal vector to their tangent spaces.

There was given a hint to look at the extremum points of the function $f(x) = <x,v>$ which means $f(x) = x_1v_1 + x_2v_2 + x_3v_3$. Since the functions is continuous and $M$ is compact then the function get a minimum and maximum on $M$. Let's say the $x$ is the maximum and $y$ is a the minimum. Moreover, I noticed that $\nabla f = (v_1,v_2,v_3) = v$.

However, I am not so sure how to continue from here. I am supposed to show that $v$ is normal to both $T_xM$ and $T_yM$ but I don't see how exactly. I still haven't used the fact that $M$ is a manifold so it probably uses that.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: You really need to tell us what definition of a manifold contained in $\Bbb{R}^2$ you are using. (Some assumptions are needed to ensure the existence of the tangent spaces.) However, to see that a minimum/maximum, $x_0$ say, of your function $f(x)$ must be at a point where $v$ is normal to the tangent bundle, consider an arbitrary differentiable curve $\gamma$ in $M$ with $\gamma(0) = x_0$ and note that $0$ is a local minimum/maximum for $f \circ \gamma$ (hence $(f \circ \gamma)'(0) = 0$).

Comment: $M$ is a manifold if for every $x \in M$ there exists an open set $U \subset R^3$ such that $M \bigcap U$ is a graph of a smooth function

Comment: That definition needs some more details, I think. How are you viewing $M \cap U$ as the graph of a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the hint you propose, $f(x)=\langle x, v\rangle$ has a maximum and a minimum. If they both coincide, it turns out that your $2$-manifold is a compact subset of a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which would imply that it is a surface with boundary, contradicting your definition of submanifold as something that is locally a graph of a function with open domain in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (Invariance of Domain implicitly used).
Then if $x_0$ is the maximum of $f$ and $\gamma: (-\epsilon, \epsilon)\rightarrow M$ is a curve with $\gamma(0)=x_0$, $t=0$ is a critical point of $f\circ \gamma$ (this is just a directional derivative of $f$ at $x_0$). This means that $0=\nabla f(x_0)\cdot \gamma'(0)=v\cdot \gamma'(0)$. This proves that $v\perp T_{x_0}M$, since $T_{x_0}M$ is exactly the plane containing all vectors tangent to curves through $x_0$.
The exact same argument proves that $v\perp T_{y_0}M$.

Comment: So the solution is working with the definition of tangent space. Thanks!

Comment: Exactly, this is one of the many definitions of tangent space. This one is very useful, because it is very geometric, but it requieres our manifold to be sitting naturally inside some $\mathbb{R}^n$. Your welcome!

Comment: @Laz: the question only makes sense for a manifold sitting inside $\Bbb{R}^3$ (it's about a relationship between a vector in $\Bbb{R}^3$ and the tangent spaces,  (which only makes sense if the tangent spaces are identified with planes in $\Bbb{R}^3$). (And it was me who provided the hint and not the OP $\ddot{\smile}$.)

Comment: Of course @RobArthan, I was refering to the definition of tangent space in the general setting.

Comment: @Laz: sure. The problem could have been phrased in terms of an immersion or embedding of an abstract differentiable manifold in $\Bbb{R}^3$, which is why I asked the OP to say more about the definitions being used. Anyway, the OP is happy with your answer, so let's go our way rejoicing.

Comment: LOL! You got it!